# Anime with a disabled main character who can walk when she bonds with a boy

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime is about a disabled girl who I assume was kind of blondish with glasses, she was tortured (and raped?) by her brother. She could gain magic powers by bonding with another boy and walk normally but for a limited time.

There are other characters who also gain powers by bonding with someone else.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  What kind of magic powers?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) to sse if they help you recall any more details.

Comment: Boy is that an awkward one to Google...

Comment: DavidW I watched it 2 years ago and it was kinda newly released at the time. One specefic power was  summoning swords.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch that doesn't warrant an answer but perhaps "Guilty Crown"? The main characters power is "to draw out the heart of a person". The powers match those of two members of the main cast: Ayase is wheelchair-bound, but with the protagonists power she can walk, while the female lead Inori enables him to summon a giant sword. Although it lacks the rape part.
Finished airing in 2012.

Comment: No It's not gulity crown for sure.  I think I may naver find out what the hell I watched two years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [Freezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing_(manga)) (Furījingu)?

> In 2065, Earth is in the middle of a war with extra-dimensional aliens called Nova. The military develops and trains Pandoras (パンドラ), girls who are able to use special genetic tissue called Stigmata (聖痕, Seikon) to manifest superhuman fighting skills and weapons. Supporting the Pandoras are male partners called Limiters (リミッター, Rimittā), who use special "freezing" powers to limit their opponent's mobility.

The character Satellizer el Bridget fits your description of blonde with glasses:

[image]

She appears to fight with a sword:

[image]

And she seems to have sexual assault in her past. From the wiki:

> At nine years old, she and her mother are taken in by the El Bridgets where she meets her father's wife Olivia and her two kids, Violet and Louis, the last of whom mistreats and then sexually abuses her.

I can’t find evidence that she cannot walk, but I thought it may be episode specific. I saw at least one reference to a fight where another character destroys her legs but apparently they regenerate

Comment: You can use a > quote box to place quotes. Also don't forget to link any sources you use.

Comment: Freezing had a disabled female character but definitely not FL. Im sure that until c200, our MC not get disabled(injured and almost death multiple time only) or at least need a guy so she can walk

Comment: Yes sorry for the lack of proper formatting. I can’t seem to do the block quotes or hyperlinks through safari on ios.